# How to model High/Low prices for Stocks with Monte Carlo

Tags: equities, monte-carlo, simulations

I'm using monte carlo simulation to model stock paths and measure risk, but I was wondering if there is a way to simulate the full bar/candle chart with open, high, low and close prices , as I'm only simulating the stock path with close prices.

Comment: easy, just simulate the intraday movements and calculate the charts from there.

Comment: Why not doing one simulation for each ohlc? Other option would be to convert ohlc back into an ordered one column data series..

Comment: It might be nice to generate the bars directly, potentially saves computation. I would think very carefully before using that as an input to something else though.

Comment: Are you just trying to synthesize pricing data?  If so why not just use real data?

Comment: what do you need it for? depending on your answer, suggestions on how to create the levels will vary.

Answer (score 4):

Some time ago I wrote an Octave C++ function to do just what you want and blogged about it on my blog. The link to the relevant post is https://dekalogblog.blogspot.com/2011/08/creation-of-synthetic-data.html where the code is freely available.

This might give you some ideas about how you might code a similar function for yourself.